# how to get the sql data in reverse order of rows

Tags: sql

i have a source table

```
Source | Desti | DIST
bng hyd 300
bng chn 200
chn bng 200
hyd bng 300
hyd pune 1000
```

desired result

output---

```
Source || Desti || DIST
hyd | pune | 1000
hyd | bng | 300
chn | bng | 200
```

i was trying something like this

```
select distinct
case when source<destination then source else destination end source,
case when source<destination then destination else source end destination,
distance
from test_table
order by distance DESC
```

is this is a simple way to write or any better ways to write ?

Comment: Rows have no intrinsic order. What criteria do you want to use to order the rows? Just distance? Then use `order by distance desc` like you have.

Comment: just distance , i was wondering do i have to use partition by or rank() functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `CASE` expressions to find each distinct source destination pair:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN source < destination THEN destination ELSE source END AS source,
    CASE WHEN source < destination THEN source ELSE destination END AS destination,
    distance
FROM test_table
ORDER BY distance DESC;
```